# C# single client that connects to several server

Tags: c#, client-server, tcp, asynchronous

I have to design a tcp-ip application based on a single client that open several connections against external server. Obviously I thought to open a different socket for each server (max 12) and use an asynchronous connection, because those server may send me data on every moments. 
Someone could point me to a efficient pattern in order to create this kind of client?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on Observer and/or Visitor.